# Linearly independent vectors from a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a product of $n$ integer-valued matrices:
$$V=M_1 M_2 \dotsm M_n \,.$$
The $M_i$ are not square matrices, but the rows of $M_i$ and the columns of $M_{i+1}$ have the same length, so the multiplications make sense.  $V$ is a matrix with a single column, so it is a vector.

When I take this product, I have two choices for each of the $M_i$, say $M_i=A_i$ or $M_i=B_i$.

Thus the naïve bound on the number of different $V$'s I can get is $2^n$.  In practice, the number of linearly independent $V$'s I can get is much much smaller.

My question is: **how can I bound the number of linearly independent $V$'s?**

For example, is it possible get a bound that depends on the ranks of the $A_i$ and $B_i$?

I would be interested in references to any place in the literature where this sort of question has been studied.

Comment: Do you want the bound as a function of $A_i$ and $B_i$, or do you want to take the supremum over all choices?  (Your example question suggests the former.)

Comment: As a function.  In more detail: the $A_i$ and $B_i$ are known matrices ($i=1,\dots,n$).  I would like to avoid computing the $2^n$ possible $V$'s and checking how many are linearly independent.  Instead I would like to have a function of the $A_i$'s and $B_i$'s that would give me some information about the number of linearly independent $V$'s they can produce.

Comment: An upper bound is $\operatorname{rank} A_1 + \operatorname{rank} B_1$. This is because all the $V$ are contained in the union of the images of $A_1$ and $B_1$, and the dimension of the span of that union is at most the sum of the ranks. (In an earlier comment I mistakenly said a similar bound would hold for each $i=1,2,\dotsc,n$. Sorry for the error.)